# Why does task wait for Task.Run before executing next code but not for Task.Factory.StartNew?

Tags: c#, wpf, task-parallel-library, async-await

At least as I've implemented it in my code, I had to modify the StartNew Task to get the same behavior. In my View there's a start button. It's IsEnabled property is bound to a Boolean in the View Model. Without adding `await task.ContinueWith(_ => true);` and moving `return true;` out of the try block, the PopulateListStartNew Task doesn't wait so the button stays enabled. I prefer to use `Task.Factory.StartNew` because passing a TaskScheduler makes for more readable code (no Dispatcher clutter). Records is an ObservableCollection.

I thought that Task.Run was basically a shortcut (per [Task.Run vs Task.Factory.StartNew](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/10/24/10229468.aspx). At any rate, I'd like to better understand the difference in behavior and would certainly appreciate any suggestions related to making my example code better.

```
public async Task<bool> PopulateListTaskRun(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    try
    {
        await Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                // Clear the records out first, if any
                Application.Current.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() => Records.Clear());


                for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                {
                    if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
                    {
                        return;
                    }

                    // Resharper says do this to avoid "Access to modified closure"
                    var i1 = i;

                    Application.Current.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() =>
                        {
                            Records.Add(new Model
                                {
                                    Name = NamesList[i1],
                                    Number = i1
                                });

                            Status = "cur: " +
                                        i1.ToString(
                                            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                        });

                    // Artificial delay so we can see what's going on
                    await Task.Delay(200);
                }

                Records[0].Name = "Yes!";
            }, cancellationToken);

        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return false;
    }
}

public async Task<bool> PopulateListStartNew(CancellationToken cancellationToken, TaskScheduler taskScheduler)
{
    try
    {
        var task = await Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
            {
                // Clear the records out first, if any
                Records.Clear();


                for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                {
                    if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
                    {
                        return;
                    }

                    Records.Add(new Model
                        {
                            Name = NamesList[i],
                            Number = i
                        });

                    Status = "cur: " +
                                i.ToString(
                                    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);


                    // Artificial delay so we can see what's going on
                    await Task.Delay(200);
                }

                Records[0].Name = "Yes!";
            }, cancellationToken, TaskCreationOptions.None, taskScheduler);

        // Had to add this
        await task.ContinueWith(_ => true);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return false;
    }

    // Had to move this out of try block
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Do you actually need the `TaskScheduler` parameter? Usually, you either want to run code in the current context (which `await` does by default), or you want to run it on the `ThreadPool`, in which case you would use `Task.Run()`.

Comment: @svick. I updated my post to mention that Records is an ObservableCollection. So, yes, I either need TaskScheduler or Dispatcher wrapping to update it and display in a bound ListView. Sorry, I should have made that clear up front.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The link you posted in your question has the answer: `Task.Run` understands and unwraps `async Task` delegates, while `StartNew` returns a `Task<Task>` instead, which you have to unwrap yourself by calling `Unwrap` or doing a double-`await`.

However, I recommend you completely rewrite the code as follows. Notes:

- Don't use `Dispatcher`. There shouldn't be a need for it with properly-written `async` code.
- Treat all your background worker methods and asynchronous operations as "services" for your UI thread. So your method will return to the UI context periodically as necessary.

Like this:

```
public async Task<bool> PopulateListTaskRunAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
  try
  {
    // Clear the records out first, if any
    Records.Clear();

    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
      cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

      Records.Add(new Model
      {
        Name = NamesList[i],
        Number = i
      });

      Status = "cur: " + i.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

      // Artificial delay so we can see what's going on
      await Task.Delay(200);
    }

    Records[0].Name = "Yes!";
    return true;
  }
  catch (Exception)
  {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey, that really helps...I've gotten into some unnecessarily complex code and *forgot* to try simple first. One thing: If I use ThrowIfCancellationRequested then the method returns false and my Start button stays disabled. I realize I'm trying to do two things - detect when the Task has stopped running and detect when it has run successfully, i.e. no cancellation or errors. I need to re-evaluate.

Comment: The easiest way to do that is to simplify the code more: remove the `try`/`catch` in `PopulateListTaskRunAsync`. The `try`/`catch` should be in the method where it's `await`ed.

Answer (score 1):

I'm too not comfortable with all this plumbing but I'll try to answer.

First why your second code does not work:

- you give **StartNew** an **async delegate** which is something like **Func<Task>** so **StartNew** will return a **Task<Task>** and you wait on the outer task which ends immediately as it consists in returning the inner Task (not really sure about that)
- then you **await** the **continuation of the inner task**, the inner thread of execution, what you intended to do; but I guess it should be the same if you awaited directly the inner task itself this way:

  ```
  await await Task.Factory.StartNew(async ...
  ```

Why your first code works:

- according to the **[MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh160382.aspx)**  **Task.Run** directly returns a **Task** object, the **inner task** I guess
- so you directly **await for the inner task**, not an intermediate one, so it just works as expected

At least this is my understanding and keep in mind I've not yet played with all this stuff (no VS 2012). :)

Comment: The second code works, just requires the modifications I show. But thanks for jogging my memory regarding the double await await. I have come across that in my reading. Will have to try it. What I'm finding difficult with all Task-related code is getting the right placement/sequence of features to get what I want. In this case, I want a ListView to be continually updating as the ObservableCollection is populated, while keeping the Window UI responsive. Customers complain about long-running code locking applications.

Comment: "the inner task I guess".  Not exactly true: it returns a task that represents the completion of both the inner and outer tasks (it works like `TaskExtensions.Unwrap`).